# Extracting data from JSON array

Tags: java, json

I know its an array, but I am completely new to JSON and need help comprehending how this is structured, here is my attempt at extracting data:

```
String JSonString = readURL("//my URL is here");
JSONArray s = JSONArray.fromObject(JSonString);
JSONObject Data =(JSONObject)(s.getJSONObject(0));
System.out.println(Data.get("name"));
```

My JSON data that I have goes like this :

```
 {
"sports": [
    {
        "name": "basketball",
        "id": 40,
        "uid": "s:40",
        "leagues": [
            {
                "name": "National Basketball Assoc.",
                "abbreviation": "nba",
                "id": 46,
                "uid": "s:40~l:46",
                "groupId": 7,
                "shortName": "NBA",
                "athletes": []
            }
        ]
    }
],
"resultsOffset": 10,
"resultsLimit": 10,
"resultsCount": 1,
"timestamp": "2013-11-18T03:15:43Z",
"status": "success"
}
```

I dont really have a strong grasp of this stuff so all the help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to extract `sports` first.

Comment: like I said, Im clueless as to how this is structured so code examples would help.

Comment: The JSON data in your question is an object (and not an array) and it's invalid. (Try http://jsonlint.com/ or a similar tool.)

Comment: then what do the brackets and curly braces represent?

Comment: An opening curly brace starts a JSON object. An opening bracket starts an array. Your data starts with a curly brace (object) and ends with a closing bracket (invalid).

Comment: I used jsonlint and its definately valid.

Comment: It's missing the closing curly.  Otherwise it's OK.

Comment: I changed it so its no "valid"

Comment: Thanks for fixing your question. The new version that includes another five elements is now valid and properly formatted.

Comment: Look at the structure.  Peel it like an onion, one layer at a time.

Comment: @Codo - Though the elements (other than the closing curly) are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: See json.org.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn the JSON syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, most Java code that uses JSON uses packages the map the JSON directly to custom Java objects, rather than mapping to generic Maps and Lists.  This makes it a lot harder to comprehend JSON in the Java environment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the idea :

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONArray sportsArray = root.getJSONArray("sports");

// now get the first element:
JSONObject firstSport = sportsArray.getJSONObject(0);

// and details of the first element
String name = firstSport.getString("name"); // basketball
int id = firstSport.getInt("id"); // 40
JSONArray leaguesArray = firstSport.getJSONArray("leagues");

// and so on, you can process leaguesArray similarly
```

It should work (feel free to complain about compile errors if there are any)

Comment: Thanks for help 1 decade back, it helped me to solve a problem today :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75519681/jsoup-document-object-how-to-parse-data-in-below-case-of-complex-html-element

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON data is an object (it starts with a curly brace). In the next inner layer, there is a single array (at key "sports"):

```
String jsonString = readURL("//my URL is here");
JSONObject result = JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray sports = result.getJSONArray("sports");
JSONObject sport = sport.getJSONObject(0);
System.out.println(sport.getString("name"));
```

I might have used another JSON library than you.

Answer (score 0):

JSON means JavaScript Object Notation.

Objects in javascripts are just containers and can be represented by key-value pairs. Please find below notations to understand about json.

Represent objects in json: E.g. Student

```
{"name" : "Robin", "rollnumber" : "1"}
```

Represent array in json : E.g. Array of students

```
[{"name" : "Robin", "rollnumber" : "1"}, {"name" : "Mark", "rollnumber" : "2"}]
```

You can understand more on JSON from diagrams on this link http://www.json.org/fatfree.html

There are various ways available to to convert JSON to javaobject and javaobject to JSON : One of them is http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score 0):

Adding detailed code here along with the imports .

If this helps.

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class extractingJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String jsonStr = "{\"name\":\"SK\",\"arr\":{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\"},\"arrArray\":[{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\"}]}";
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        String name = jsonObj.getString("name");
        System.out.println(name);

        String first = jsonObj.getJSONObject("arr").getString("a");
        System.out.println(first);

        first = jsonObj.getJSONArray("arrArray").getJSONObject(0).getString("a");
        System.out.println(first);



    }


}
```