# Java Extracting Data from JSON Not Working

Tags: java, json

I was having some problem when trying to extract information out from JSON. Here is the example of my JSON:

```
// removed
```

My responseMessage is just a string. And my code to extract the info out:

```
// removed
```

I tried to follow the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058240/extracting-data-from-json-array) However, nothing has been printed out and there is no error message. Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I realized the problem is due to this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject`

However, if I changed my import for JSONObject to `import org.json.simple.JSONObject;` the code above will break. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Also, your json doesn't seem to be valid, you need to put `response` in curly braces.

Comment: Down voter mind to explain?

Comment: Your root doesn't have `schedules` array but it's nested under `response`. Apart from this there doesn't seem to be any obvious error. Separate note, paste json instead of image.

Comment: I'm able to print `username` with similar code. Though I used `gson`. Debugging is the only solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185455/discussion-between-sukhpal-singh-and-hyperfkcb).

Comment: What you have posted here is not valid JSON. JSON uses double quotes around property names and strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked in comments, below code is working using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject root =  (JsonObject) parser.parse(json);
JsonArray schedulesArray = root.getAsJsonObject("response").getAsJsonArray("schedules");
JsonObject firstSchedule = (JsonObject) schedulesArray.get(0);
String userName = firstSchedule.get("username").getAsString();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a “stupid” method.First,you should create three DTOs,it's may like this:

```
public class Schedule {
    private String username;
    private String scheduleId;
    private String SCHEDULEsTARTtIME;
    private String NOTES;
    private String familyName;
    private String principalId;
    private String friendlyName;
    private String scheduleEndTime;

    // get set methods
}

public class ResponseInfo {
    private String instrumentName;
    private String instrumentId;
    private String instrumentType;
    private List<Schedule> schedules;
}

public class Response {
    private ResponseInfo response;
}
```

then,convert response string to Response DTO

```
Response newResponse = mapper.readValue(content,Response.class);
```

Comment: Why not just use the JSONParser to parse the string responseMessage to JSON instead?

Comment: Just used to it，you must first get the value of key "response" like JSONObject tmp = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(content);JSONObject resp = (JSONObject)tmp.get("response");

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONArray schedulesArray = root.getJSONArray("schedules");
```

replace it with the following:

```
JSONObject response = root.getJSONObject("response");
JSONArray schedulesArray = response.getJSONArray("schedules");
```

then try again.

Comment: Nope it does not work. It is the same as the code snippet I just updated